# Fetching values for query dynamically and firing on button click PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page where I have two columns one is Attribute name and Attribute Value. I have a button named Add Attribute Value which adds text boxes to the screen so that an Attribute Name can have multiple Attribute values. I have added the text boxes with a variable i in javascript.

I need to use the "i" variable and also access the text in the textbox using the name "'mytext'+i".

The code written is below:

```
<html>
<head><title>Add Attributes</title></head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
var i = 1;
function changeIt()
{

my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='mytext'+ i><br>"
i++;
}
</script>
<form action= "" method = "POST">
<h1 align = "center"><u>Attribute Management</u></h1>

 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 Attribute Name Attribute Value <br>
 <br><input type="text" name="attname" > 
     <input type="text" name="attvalue">
     <input type="button" value="Add Attribute Value" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="my_div"></div>

 <b> </b><br>
          <br><br><input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Add Attribute" > &nbsp; 
          <input type="submit" name = "submit1" value = "User Application" >
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $att_name = $_POST['attname'];

    $query_string1 = "ALTER TABLE users ADD $att_name varchar(20)";
    $query_string2 = "ALTER TABLE attributes ADD $att_name varchar(20)";
    $part_string = "(";
    for($x = 0;$x<= i;$x++){
        $att_value= $_POST['mytext'.$x];
        if($x = 0){
        $part_string = $part_string.$att_value;
        }
        else{
        $part_string = ",".$part_string.$att_value;
        }
    }
    $part_string= $part_string.")";
    $query_string3 = "INSERT INTO attributes ('$att_name') VALUES '$part_string'";
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","nets") or die("Couldn't connect to database");        
    /*$query1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query_string1);
    $query2 = mysqli_query($connect,$query_string2);
    $query3 = mysqli_query($connect,$query_string3);*/
}
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
header('Location: RegisteredUsers.php');
}
?>
```

Get an error of "i" is not defined and "Undefined index: mytext0". I have to collect all the attribute values and fire a query with all the values from the text box together.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The error of "Undefined index: mytext0" is come due to no such input field is defined, because you have initialised the i with 1 so, just make it 0.

And also you have a issue in the html, which you are adding, just change your script block with following :

```js
var i = 1;
function changeIt()
{

my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='mytext"+ i+"'><br>"
i++;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Add Attributes</title></head>
<body>

<form action= "" method = "POST">The error of "Undefined index: mytext0" is come due to no such input field is defined, because you have initialised the i with 1 so, just make it 0. 

And also you have a issue in the html, which you are adding, just change your script block with following :

<h1 align = "center"><u>Attribute Management</u></h1>

 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 Attribute Name Attribute Value <br>
 <br><input type="text" name="attname" > 
     <input type="text" name="attvalue">
     <input type="button" value="Add Attribute Value" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="my_div"></div>

 <b> </b><br>
          <br><br><input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Add Attribute" > &nbsp; 
          <input type="submit" name = "submit1" value = "User Application" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I get the values from the all the textboxes to write a query ?